# Siege cannot perform load testing for more than 255 tests

Tags: software-installation

My Siege version is 4.0.2 and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Siege is installed in `./.linuxbrew/Cellar/siege/4.0.2/etc/`.

I couldn't make a load more than 255 tests and I'm getting a warning message as  you can see below:

```
 $ siege -c1000 -t5m  http://192.168.1.11:8080/
 WARNING: The number of users is capped at 255.  To increase this
         limit, search your .siegerc file for 'limit' and change
         its value. Make sure you read the instructions there...
================================================================
** SIEGE 4.0.2
** Preparing 255 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
HTTP/1.1 403     1.50 secs:     819 bytes ==> GET  /kiosk/start
HTTP/1.1 403     1.50 secs:     819 bytes ==> GET  /kiosk/start
HTTP/1.1 403     1.51 secs:     819 bytes ==> GET  /kiosk/start
HTTP/1.1 403     1.52 secs:     819 bytes ==> GET  /kiosk/start
```

And so on. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to terminate the command.

Then I  edited the `siegerc` file (`sudo vim siegerc`) as follows:

```
verbose = true
color = on
quiet = false
show-logfile = true
logging = false
limit = 3000
protocol = HTTP/1.1
chunked = true
cache = false
concurrent = 3000
connection = close
```

Even after restarting my machine, I still get the same warning message and loading only my 255 tests.

What should I do to run more than that?

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/load-testing-with-siege/, it appears that if you run `siege.config`, it will create a `.siegerc` for you, which you can then update per your requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. **;-)** Upvoted already, but if you [edit] your answer and add a bit more info, it'll surely attract more upvotes...

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-R` option to read the configuration from the `.siegerc` file, similar to:

```
$ siege -R .siegerc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

check the file descriptors limit:

```
ulimit -n
```

Then set it to higher number:

```
ulimit -n 4096
```